# trouble searching hashmap and averaging objects in arraylist

Tags: java

In this program I want to input fake stocks and search for them by stock symbol and print the average cost of the last 250 stocks bought.  Here is where I am so far, whenever I input 2, the program crashes without any error messages.

```
package stocks;

import java.util.*;

public class Stocks {
    private String sym;
    private List<Purchase> purchases;

    public Stocks(final String symbol) {
        this.sym = symbol;
        purchases = new ArrayList<Purchase>();
    }

    public void addPurchase(final int amt, final double cost) {
        purchases.add(new Purchase(amt, cost));
    }

    public String getSym() {
        return sym;
    }

    public void setSym() {
        this.sym = sym;
    }

    public double getAvg250() {
        int i = 0;
        int total = 0;
        int shares = 0;
        while (i < purchases.size()) {
            Purchase p = purchases.get(i);
            if (shares + p.getAmt() >= 250) {
                total += (250 - shares) * p.getCost();
                shares = 250;
                break;
            }
            shares += p.getAmt();
            i++;
        }
        return total * 1.0 / shares;
    }

    public class Purchase {
        private int amt;
        private int cost;

        public Purchase(int amt, double cost) {

        }

        public int getAmt() {
            return amt;
        }

        public void setAmt(int amt) {
            this.amt = amt;
        }

        public int getCost() {
            return cost;
        }

        public void setCost(int cost) {
            this.cost = cost;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int choice = 0;
        ArrayList<Stocks> StocksList = new ArrayList<Stocks>();
        Map<String, Stocks> stocks = new HashMap<String, Stocks>();

        while (choice == 0) {
            System.out.println("Enter 1 to input a new stock, or 2 to query a stock's price, 3 to quit: ");
            Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(System.in);
            choice = sc1.nextInt();

            if (choice == 1) {

                Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println("Please enter the stock symbol: ");
                String sym = sc2.next();
                System.out.println("Please enter the number of shares: ");
                int amt = sc2.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Please enter the price per share: ");
                double cost = sc2.nextDouble();

                Stocks s = stocks.get(sym);
                if (s == null) {
                    s = new Stocks(sym);
                    stocks.put(sym, s);
                }
                s.addPurchase(amt, cost);

                choice = 0;

                if (choice == 2) {
                    Scanner sc3 = new Scanner(System.in);
                    System.out.println("Please enter the symbol of the stock you wish to see: ");
                    String search = sc3.next();

                    if (stocks.containsKey(search)) {

                        System.out.println(search + "'s LIFO price is " + s.getAvg250());
                        choice = 0;
                    }
                }
                if (choice == 3) {

                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should isolate the part you're struggling with and post that, describing exactly what is it that you can't work out—posting your entire project is not really in accordance with Stackoverflow style.

Comment: Right now whenever I input 2, the program closes without any errors. I'm not sure which part of the program to isolate for that.

Comment: My comment wasn't a question; I was saying you should clean out the irrelevant noise from your question.

Comment: Oh my mistake, I thought you meant the code itself.

Comment: I did mean the code: you pasted your entire program; instead you should only paste the smallest possible snippet of code that helps others understand what your problem is.

Comment: `if (choice == 1) { if (choice == 2){} }` I think your logic is wrong. You should use `if (choice == 1) {} else if (choice == 2) {}` not nested condition checking.

Answer (score 0):

You check whether the user entered "2" within the if block for checking if the user entered "1". And because choice is still 2 after the `if (choice == 1)` block your program leaves the while loop.

Should be something like (if you keep this style of programming)

```
while (choice == 0) {
   // ...
   if (choice == 1) {
   } 
   if (choice == 2) {
   }
   if (choice == 3) {
     break;
   }
   // ...
   choice = 0
}
```

instead of

```
while (choice == 0) {
   // ...
   if (choice == 1) {

      choice = 0;

      // choice 2 will never be true 
      if (choice == 2) {
      }

   }
}
```